# How to verify whether a Button is clicked or not with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify whether a button is clicked or not with Selenium WebDriver using Java. How can I verify this?

Comment: By checking if the action that the button is supposed to do is done. :)

Comment: By the way, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please include what you have done for that.

Comment: If you are clicking on a button, it performs some operation. Then you need to check whether the result of the operation is as expected or not

Comment: @kocko: I did not implement any code. I only thought 2 ways: 1) by checking the desired action that the button is suppose to do (you already mentioned) 2) If it could be possible by JS

Comment: Thanks kocko and Harsha for sharing idea

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isClickable(WebElement webe){
try
{ 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webe));
   return true;
 }
catch (Exception e)
{
return false;
 }

boolean bst = className.isClickable("your element");
```